# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7 for correctly indexed array

Tags: java, arrays, csv, bufferedreader, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a CSV file with 8 columns:

[image]

I have put each column into an array with the following code

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    List<String> wholefile = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> id = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> property_address = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> first_name = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> last_name = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> email = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> owner_address = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> price = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> date_sold = new ArrayList<String>();


    Path filepath = Paths.get("./data.csv");


    try {

      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("./data.csv"));
       String line;
       while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
         wholefile.add(line);
         String[] cols = line.split(",");
         id.add(cols[0]);
         property_address.add(cols[1]);
         first_name.add(cols[2]);
         last_name.add(cols[3]);
         email.add(cols[4]);
         owner_address.add(cols[5]);
         price.add(cols[6]);
       }
      System.out.println(id);
      System.out.println(property_address);
      System.out.println(first_name);
      System.out.println(last_name);
      System.out.println(email);
      System.out.println(owner_address);
      System.out.println(price);


   } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

when I run this code I get the following output:

```
id = [id,1,2,3,4,5...]
property_address = [property address, 94032 Mockingbird Alley, 293 Haas Lane, 75 Ruskin Lane...]
```

and so on just like I expect!

However when I add

```
date_sold.add(cols[7]);
```

I get a error that

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7

I do not know why as there are 8 columns and I have started indexing from 0.
Is there something wrong with my while statement ?

Comment: What did you observe when you stepped through your code with a debugger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of [split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) you're invoking removes trailing empty strings.

> Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array

Your first row has `date_sold` column empty. Try invoking split like this instead:

```
String[] cols = line.split(",", -1);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I can tick as answered in 6 minutes, sorry I am not ranked enough to vote up either

Answer (score 0):

At first glance i don't see anything wrong but i guess statement for second entry `line.split(",")` is not considering last column which is empty.  when Try to debug it with Sys.out statement and check which row is creating the problem.